# JQuery Form validation Plugin validating single field

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

Hi I am using this form validation Plugin to validate a form
http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

I need to check one email field valid and it exists in db or not.

any solutions appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

First use that plugin to validate if email field is correct. After that use for example .ajax()-function from jquery to send validated email to server. I don't know what is your backend, so it is hard to say how exactly you should do the backend part, but basicly you need to do database query which checks if email is in the database or not. After that function can return value to client and so on...

Comment: Thanks,
I want know how to check the email field with the plugin, value entered is correct email format or not, thats all.

Comment: @Mohandass, check their [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)